# Count unique strings in table

Tags: mysql

I have the following table (yes, the id_str are integers formatted as text):

```
messages
-------------------------
id (INT) id_str (VARCHAR)
-------------------------
1        3245346543343247
2        3245346543343247
3        3245346543343247
4        1214354546578886
5        9979679595696599
6        9979679595696599
```

The desired output is a count of all unique id_str's:

```
id_str            cnt
---------------------
3245346543343247  3
1214354546578886  1
9979679595696599  2
```

I'm trying to accomplish this with the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(id_str) AS id_str, COUNT(id) FROM messages
```

But this returns the exact table as is, with the total number of messages as a second column. What am I doing wring?

Comment: The `DISTINCT` keyword operates on ALL of the expressions in the select list. The parenthesis around the first expression are unnecessary, they don't modify the behavior of the statement.

Answer (score 7):

You need to use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT id_str, COUNT(id) as cnt
FROM messages
GROUP BY id_str
```

Comment: @Jeremy: If we only want to count rows where the `id` column is not null, then yes, this is the normative pattern for returning the result set.

Comment: Well, it's a reasonable assumption that the ID is a primary key, but your implication is noteworthy; if the id field is nullable, the query results may be skewed.

Comment: @spencer7593, if I were writing the query from scratch I personally would have used `count(*)` instead of `count(id)`, but since the OP was using `count(id)` I saw no compelling reason to change that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT id_str AS id_str, COUNT(id) 
FROM messages group by id_str
```

Comment: your column names do not match the desired results.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you a count of rows for each distinct value of id_str. Note that this will count all of the rows.

```
SELECT id_str, COUNT(1) AS cnt FROM messages GROUP BY id_str
```

If you only want to count rows where a given expression is not null (for example, where `id` is not null) then you can apply the COUNT aggregate to that expression. Only rows that have a non-NULL value for the expression will be included in the count (so that it's possible, under some conditions, to actually return a count of zero):

```
SELECT id_str, COUNT(id) AS cnt FROM messages GROUP BY id_str
```

(Of course, if the `id` column is guaranteed to be NOT NULL, then these two will return the same result.)

NOTE: You don't need a DISTINCT keyword, the GROUP BY clause does what you need.

Your query is equivalent to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id_str, COUNT(id) FROM messages
```

The DISTINCT keyword operates on ALL the expressions in the SELECT list, not just the first one. The parenthesis around the first expression doesn't change the behavior.  `DISTINCT` is a reserved word, it's not a function call.  The `AS id_str` alias in your query is being assigned to just the the id_str column, which just happens to be enclosed in the unnecessary (but legal and allowed) parenthesis.

Comment: The column names don't match the desired result set.

Comment: @Jeremy Holovacs: you are exactly right, good catch.  I've modified my answer, and added the `AS cnt` alias to the `COUNT(1)` expression. I was working from the OP's original SQL statement, which also does not include the alias for the expression. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need a group by.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(id_str) AS id_str, COUNT(id) FROM messages GROUP BY id_str
```

Comment: I don't think you need distinct once you have the group by.

Comment: @Jesse: you are exactly right.  That DISTINCT keyword operates on the entire SELECT list, not just on the first expression.  It's not a function, although to some it may appear that way because the first expression is enclosed in (unnecessary) parenthesis.

Comment: This is not the way to do this.